# How to use inline ternary with data-bind variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm currently creating a footer with Save/Cancel/Delete, depending on where the user is. Now I'm trying to not show/render the Delete button when it's not required. How to achieve this using a variable from KnockoutJS (observable) as the operator in a ternary?

Current code doesn't work properly but below anyway.

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="back" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: cancelProduct">@(Global.ButtonCancel)</a></li>
<script>
    var button = "<li><a href=\"#\" data-icon=\"delete\" data-theme=\"b\" data-bind=\"click: deleteProduct\">@(Global.ButtonDelete)</a></li>";
    isEditingProduct ? button : false;
</script>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="check" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: saveProduct">@(Global.ButtonSave)</a></li>
```

The error i keep getting is that "isEditingProduct" is undefined. When i use it inline (outside the script), for a straight `<li data-bind="isEditingProduct" ></li>` with the other stuff inside it works. It hides the button, but leaves me with a gaping hole in the footer. Which is why I'm trying to get around it by not loading it in for rendering at all if it's not yet needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wish people would actually answer the question, too.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your code, I'm confused.

No idea why you feel you need a ternary to hide/unhide elements.

Use the **visible:** binding.

```
<li data-bind="visible: isEditingProduct"></li>
```

isEditingProduct needs to be a property on your view model.

Comment: I tried this, however it leaves me a blank empty space in between the <li> elements where the delete button is "invisible". Instead of <cancel><save> it does <cancel><blank><save>. isEditingProduct is a property on the viewModel which gets set to either true/false when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `visible` or `if` binding:

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="back" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: cancelProduct">@(Global.ButtonCancel)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: deleteProduct, if: isEditingProduct">@(Global.ButtonDelete)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="check" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: saveProduct">@(Global.ButtonSave)</a></li>
```

Read documentation about these bindings:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you "isEditingProduct" is defined but you can't simply reference a part of your View Model in JavaScript without fully qualifying it. Instead try:

```
myViewModel.isEditingProducts = true;
```

Also, the location of your script block is confusing. It shouldn't be in-lined between `<li />` tags. The script will not necessarily execute at that time (as the browser is parsing your markup).